# Transferring Files from Ubuntu Mate Live USB with limited functionality (Bus error core dumped)

Tags: chrome, live-usb, file-transfer, core-dump, ubuntu-mate

I'm encountering a challenging situation on an Ubuntu Mate 16.04 Live USB:

- **Unable to run commands or open GUI apps:** I'm getting a "Bus error (core dumped)" when attempting to execute commands.
- **GUI apps that were already open are still functioning.**
- **Goal:** I need to copy entire directories and files, including hidden ones, to an external hard drive.
- **Constraints:**

  - Caja file manager crashed, preventing direct file transfer.
  - Terminal functionality is limited due to the "Bus error" issue.

**Workaround attempts:**

- **Chromium:** Uploaded non-hidden directories to Google Drive, but hidden files not visible in "Select Folder to Upload" dialog.
- **Chromium:** Can access files using file:/// paths, but it can only download individual files. I have to open subdirectories one by one.
- **DownThemAll! extension:** I've used DownThemAll! to download multiple files at once, but it still requires manual subdirectory navigation.

**So, my question is:**

Is there a way to copy entire directories, including their subdirectories and hidden files, to my external hard drive using the limited functionality I currently have (Chromium)?

**Any suggestions or workarounds would be greatly appreciated!**

**Please note:**

- I'm unable to use terminal commands or open new GUI apps due to the "Bus error" issue.
- I'm hoping to find a solution that works within the constraints of my current environment.